# minitest .rb:63:in `block in autorun' while running individual Minitest function

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to run a specific test in Minitest like this.

```
ruby my_test_file.rb --name=test_fun_name
```

and I get the following error :

```
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:670:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:670:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:134:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
```

However when I run `ruby my_test_file.rb` its working fine.

**Minitest version: 5.10.2**

I got the issue on Minitest 5.10.3 as well.

**Ruby version: 2.3.3**

What could be the issue?

Comment: try `ruby -Itest my_test_file.rb --name=test_fun_name` or `ruby -Ilib my_test_file.rb --name=test_fun_name`, it passes the load paths manually.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: No, It did not help.

Comment: Could that be path issue ? How to fix it in that case ?